# cannot create cache directory on mac in laravel 5.3

Tags: macos, caching, laravel-5, composer-php

After i installed composer in mac os sierra then installed laravel framework 5.3, i cannot create cache directory or my directory is not writable, Proceeding without cache ( below detail error when installing laravel framework )

Please give me advise how to fix my problem, cause i'm newbie using mac

Thanks,

[problem picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hV55o.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

My best advice is to use [Laravel Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/homestead) instead of running the Laravel directly on Mac OSX.

1. Homestead installation on Laracasts: [Hello to laravel homestead](https://laracasts.com/lessons/say-hello-to-laravel-homestead-two) or
   [Laravel 5 Fundamentals](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/2)

This should be enough for local development. If you want to go online look at the following steps:

2. Create a [Bitbucket repository](https://bitbucket.org/)
3. Link your homestead to the bitbucket (That’s the tricky part). You will need to have [SSH setup](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-ssh-for-git-728138079.html). [This video](https://laracasts.com/series/git-me-some-version-control/episodes/1) should give you some hint. (Remember, you do not have to install git as it is included in homestead)
   By the way, [this is my go to resources for git](http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/).

Once that done, the worse is behind you.

4. Use Forge, [this videos](https://laracasts.com/series/server-management-with-forge/episodes/1) explains everything pretty well

It may seem like a lot, but in reality that will give you a really scalable environment that will spare you *tons* of trouble in the future.